# How make posts on the main page as this template?

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system

At this template [Vertex](http://dessign.net/vertex/) implemented slider at the top of the site, then just below the new conclusion in the form of pictures and captions. Please tell me how can I bring a similar way to all the main page? Straight if possible it is identical.

Comment: have you created the post you want to display on main page??

Comment: Yes i have 10 posts

Comment: Go to setting -> reading-> make you main page post page and make your main page-> front page..hope you under stand